# How to find $\displaystyle\operatorname{min}_{x>0} \frac{1}{x} \log\left(\frac{2}{x+1}\right)$?

Tags: calculus, optimization

According to Wolfram Alpha, the minimum of this is some function of the Lambert W function evaluated at $-\dfrac{1}{2e}$, but having never come across this function, I have absolutely no idea how to go about showing this. Cheers.

Comment: What happens when you take the derivative? And when you try to set the derivative equal to $0$?

Comment: I found that it attains its minimum at the value of $x$ for which $\frac{x+1}{2} e^{- \frac{x}{x+1}} = 1$, but I cannot reduce this to an expression for $x$ to then find the minimum value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Denote the function by $f$. We have

$$f'(x)=-\frac{1}{x^2}\ln\left(\frac{2}{x+1}\right)-\frac{1}{x(x+1)}$$

So $f'(x)=0$ when

$$\frac{1}{x}\ln\left(\frac{2}{x+1}\right)=-\frac{1}{x+1}.\tag{1}$$

Let $x^*$ denote the solution to this equation (we can show there exists such a unique value). From $(1)$ the minimum, $f^*$, is given by

$$f^*=f(x^*)=-\frac{1}{x^*+1}$$

Now taking the exponential of equation (1) gives

$$\frac{2}{x+1}=\exp\left(-\frac{x}{x+1}\right)$$

or

$$\frac{2}{x+1}=\exp\left(\frac{1}{x+1}-1\right)$$

or

$$-\frac{1}{2e}=-\frac{1}{x+1}e^{-\frac{1}{x+1}}.$$

Thus the minimum $f^*$ is the solution to the equation

$$-\frac{1}{2e}=f^*e^{f^*}$$

By definition, for any real number $z$, the Lambert $W$ function satisfies

$$z=W(z)e^{W(z)}$$

Thus $f^*=W(-\frac{1}{2e})$ is the minimum.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for, thanks!